# Reverse POCO Generator: How to Rename a Reverse Foreign Key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, code-generation, poco

I am using Simon Hughes' Entity-Framework Reverse POCO Generator to generate code-first EF classes for my Sql Server database.  The generator is highly configurable and I am well-aware of how to rename the foreign-key column on the many-to-one side of the relationship.  I cannot figure out how to make the generator rename the reverse relationship.

For example, I have a table named Product_User with a column named User_Info_ID that references table USER_INFO. When I run the generator, the one-to-many relationship in the User class is defined as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Child ProductUsers where [Product_User].[User_Info_ID] point to this entity (FK_PRODUCT_USER_User)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ProductUser> User1 { get; set; } // Product_User.FK_PRODUCT_USER_User
```

How do I get it to generate this instead?

```
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ProductUser> UserProducts { get; set; }
```

Comment: CORRECTION:  An override that I included in Settings.ForeignKeyName = (tableName, foreignKey, foreignKeyName, relationship, attempt) was responsible for generating "User1" as the reverse navigation name.  After correcting my mistake, It generated "ProductUsers" as the reverse FK name.  I still can't figure out how to rename the reverse navigation to "UserProducts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the *.tt file's

```
Settings.ForeignKeyName = (tableName, foreignKey, foreignKeyName, relationship, attempt) => {

    if (foreignKey.PkTableName == "USER_INFO" && foreignKey.FkTableName == "Product_User" 
        && foreignKey.FkColumn == "User_Info_ID" && relationship == Relationship.OneToMany)
        return "UserProducts";

}
```

The properties of the foreignKey parameter have the values that appear in the database schema, not the camel-case friendly output of the generator.  I found this out the hard way by setting a breakpoint inside the *.tt file and invoking [Debug T4 Template] by right-clicking the *.tt file in the VS.NET Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The Reverse POCO Project generates code using code text template. The tt that is responsible for generating the column names and property names of classes would be in the EF.Reverse.POCO.Core.ttinclude

The GetUniqueColumnName goes thru a series of steps to arrive at the name. There may be a unique name clash for it and thats why it sequences/serializes the column name with a 1 at the end.

I have attached the image of this procedure. You could also write something to the console and watch the output window as you save the database.tt to see what is going on.

[This is the screenshot of the EF.Reverse.POCO.core.ttinclude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLkLT.png)